# How to get a string by identifying the last position of a character [0-9A-Z,."#*] of the sentence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob

**Limitations: Maximum string length is 268,435,456 Unicode characters (256 mega characters) or 536,870,912 bytes. This is the size limit.**

This is the Situation: I need the size limit from the last character. Oracle throws off errors like

> : inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

How to fix such errors, Is XMLAGG an option?

**Below is the test code:**

```
`  WITH q AS (
SELECT 'All aboard! 

Hahahahaha

Aye Aye Aye Aye Aye Aye...
Crazy, but that s how it goes
Millions of people living as foes
Maybe it s not too late

To learn how to love and forget how to hate
Mental wounds not healing
Life s a bitter shame
I m going off the rails on a crazy train
I m going off the rails on a crazy train

I ve listened to preachers, I ve listened to fools
I ve watched all the dropouts who make their own rules
One person conditioned to rule and control
The media sells it and you live the role

Mental wounds still screaming
Driving me insane
I m going off the rails on a crazy train
I m going off the rails on a crazy train

I know that things are going wrong for me
You gotta listen to my words

Yeah
Heirs of a cold war, that s what we ve become
Inheriting troubles, I m mentally numb
Crazy, I just cannot bear
I m living with something that just isn t fair
Mental wounds stop healing
Who and what s to blame

I m going off the rails on a crazy train' AS sentence FROM DUAL)

SELECT SUBSTR(sentence,-256) AS Y FROM Q; `
```

**Results:**

> Yeah
>   Heirs of a cold war, that s what we ve become
>   Inheriting troubles, I m mentally numb
>   Crazy, I just cannot bear
>   I m living with something that just isn t fair
>   Mental wounds stop healing
>   Who and what s to blame
>   I m going off the rails on a crazy train

**Test Scenarios: The code must return values for the below scenarios**

' Hello we have 14. apples in the basket, we are shipping them to
Japan via Australia for $23142 using #1243432 flight number '

' How can the plastic pretend on top of the supported newcomer? Why can t the horror exceed the charitable knight? The helmet thinks! How does whatever ward misprint the transmitter? The higher kernel ignores a collective with the aware array. An anatomy laughs around the back defect?'

' 949490909232 Yo Whats up?'

' Thanks'

'5/16/1941'

' 1. Hi man

2. This is not the best Idea;
3. Is Soccer the worlds popular sport
4. How many Elephants can fit in the White House
5. A lion can eat 
    6 deer, 4 zebra and 8 buffalos in 2 years.'

Comment: What is your expected result.

Comment: Done, But my code does not work for the Test Scenarios. I have 5 scenarios in my question.

Comment: I am still not able to understand what are you expecting from `' Thanks'`?

Comment: ' Thanks' is the input, So the output is ' Thanks'. Same like '5/16/1941' the output is '5/6/1941'

Comment: Ok, So do you want if the string is more than 256 characters long then only 256 characters else pick the whole string?

Comment: 256 characters from the end of the String, If the string is less than that then the entire string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this -

```
SELECT SUBSTR(sentence,-LENGTH(sentence), 256) AS Y
FROM Q;
```

Comment: Is there a faster way to do it, without the case statement?

Comment: I have a doubt that this can be achieved without using case statement.

Comment: I remember doing substr(Column, length(column), -256) I think there is something wrong in my syntax. But, Instead of length I need to use find the position of the last character to get accurate results.

Comment: @StackOne, You are absolutely correct. Try the edited version.